# Android operating system with touchscreen?

Tags: pi-2, android, pitft

So, I bought a "LCD Display, Kuman 3.5 Inch 480x320 TFT Touch Screen Monitor for Raspberry Pi" from Amazon. Now, I thought it was plug and go, but it's not. No biggy, I decided to figure out how to use it anyways. But, I can't find anything online about what I want to do, and I'm horrible with coding.

So, here is what I want. I was to run an Android operating system using this screen. So, how would I get the drivers and run them through the Android os? Is that even possible?

Comment: Most Screens for the RPi (except the official one) use proprietary GPIO Communication (well some over SPI some over I2C). So they need to be identified and the communication has to be set up accordingly. The way they work on RPi is that they have an EEPROM telling Raspbian, how to configure the GPIO. This setup is proprietary in Raspbian.
So I think you will be out of luck using Android. But I believe it can work with the official Display which is using the DSI interface which is common to all mobile phones.

Answer (score 3):

[disclaimer]
While not on Android OS, I'd like to share my experience on getting it running a minimal debian/raspbian based Linux distro - Minibian `https://minibianpi.wordpress.com/download/`.

This device seems to be the same as the one here `http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)` so those instructions work too

### H/W wise

- Raspberry Pi 3 (the latest model out there as of this writing)
- 5V/2.5A power supply (wall wart)
- 4 GB class 4 micro SD (Sandisk)
- HDMI cable and LED monitor required to verify the OS was written correctly on the card and install the required device drivers
- USB keyboard / mouse
- network / internet connection

### setup

- connect power supply, network

### S/W wise

- Ubuntu running on personal laptop - for creating the bootable card

### steps:

- Download the compressed image from the minibian web site and extract the .img from it
- Inserted the microsd into an adapter and then into the laptop
- It showed up as `/dev/sdb` on my machine which might be different on yours
- I used the dd command (required super user privilege though) to write the image into the disk using the instructions here

`www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/linux.md`

- moved the card from the laptop onto the Pi and powered up
- this booted it up the OS with the boot log showing up on the LED monitor
- during this time,assuming the module is correctly connected to the Pi, the display should be completely white. this is a good sign that the device is atleast getting the power
- the next step was to get the drivers on to the new OS
- download the driver archive using 
  `wget http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/3/3d/LCD-show-160811.tar.gz` 
  on to the raspberry pi
- extract the contents 
  `tar xvf LCD-show-160811.tar.gz`
- cd into the extracted folder and execute the driver installer
  `cd ./LCD-show`
  `./LCD35-show` here 35 maps to 3.5" display
- this should show some brief disk activity followed by a reboot
- on reboot the boot log should show up on the TS/Display

[image: TFT with boot screen]
I realize this doesnt answer your question on getting it running on android, I hope these steps are atleast useful to verify you have a working piece.