# How can I install the KUMAN 3.5 inch-display?

Tags: pi-3, boot-issues, touchscreen

I have a perfectly running Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, with a Raspbian Distribution on a 16 GB SD-Card. I connected a Screen with a HDMI-to-DVI Connector to it, a Mouse and Keyboard and I also have SSH access. Further I got a Kuman 3.5 Inch Touch-Display, which I want to use on it. I read myself through the Internet enough that I know I can't use the Screen and the HDMI-Screen simultaneously. So I connected the Screen to the right Pins, the Backlight already works. So I take the Drivers that are sent with it. Searched the one for my Distribution, extracted the Script onto my Raspberry Pi and launched it through./LCD-35 in the terminal. After a few seconds it Reboots and the Color-Test appears. The Screen for the NOOBS-Recovery-Mode appears, which I can still use, then a few seconds later:

> ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)

I can unplug it, like I said, the color-test and the recovery and the same again, regardless of having the HDMI-Cable, the Display, USB-Mouse/Keyboard plugged in or not. Before I made a .img of my card so I can flash it again to have my old state, nonetheless, the LCD won't get to work through that.

Can you help me configuring the LCD? I already tried it 2 times this way, both times the same.

UPDATE: I installed a IMG of Raspbian sent with the Display, which worked, let's say 50 %. It worked as a mini-screen, but not more. The touch wouldn't work. I tried to calibrate it, read and did the instructions for my screen, but nothing helped. It's not the original problem but I'd still rather install it on a working system without the special Raspbian.

Comment: Have you validated your connection between the display and the Pi

Comment: How would i validate it? Do you mean physically or on software-level?

Comment: Have you tried using different SD cards?

Comment: Im making a second SD-Card right now to try it, but what did you mean by validating it?

Comment: I ment to say to see if you have connect f it correctly but since you are getting some output from the Pi it's likely not a wiring problem

Comment: Definitely not, there are no wires, its plugged onto the GPIO pins with a Connector that's mounted on the back of the screen. And like i wrote in the Update, the Screen itself worked but no touch, and only on a special Distribution thats made for this screen. But i know its possible on a custom/classic (how you want to call it :D) one.

Comment: So currently is your only problem with the touchscreen or still with the display if so could you share a photo of the display?

Comment: At first i'd like to get the screen working on my Pi with the my old/custom one where i already configured everything. So, at my problem, the screen still isnt workin. But i know its not a Display-Problem because it already worked in another constellation. Here's a link to the screen: https://www.amazon.de/Kuman-Resolution-Display-Interface-Raspberry-pi/dp/B01CNLYL1C

Comment: Hello, i bought same Kuman touch display and now facing same error like you. Did you solved your problem @NicolasFischer ?? Please let me know what steps u took to solve this. TIA

Comment: The only way i got it to work is without the Touchscreen. Im starting to believe its a manufacturing-side mistake because i tried 10 to 20 images at this point and none of them was able to make the touch work. If you need help to at least get the Screen to work, just ask :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here are the drivers and the description](https://mega.nz/#F!HUFQFDwL!fhM7RPrhbMJLsZ7ISLEr0A) of how to install the screen given by [Kumantech](http://kumantech.com/help/documents-and-recources_h0037.html). I got it working, and touch screen functionality also worked. I actually did this with combination with other [tutorial](http://www.circuitbasics.com/setup-lcd-touchscreen-raspberry-pi/). Issues I had was that the Pi froze on next reboot, but I'm not sure if error was mine, or just weird faith. I'll be playing around with this now and I'll post my further results.

Comment: As this question was the first hit for a Google of "_kuman driver download pi 3.5"_", I thought I'd update the link if anyone has trouble. This is to update @HelpNeeder's answer after trying their first "**_Here are the drivers and the description_**" link as it kept sending me to a "Not found due to _[reasons]_". I think that the link should point to [here](https://mega.nz/#F!HUFQFDwL!fhM7RPrhbMJLsZ7ISLEr0A).

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the driver from [here](http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/3/3d/LCD-show-160811.tar.gz).
2. Add to `/boot/config.txt` file the following lines:

   ```
   max_usb_current=1
   hdmi_group=2
   hdmi_mode=87
   hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
   ```
3. Uncompress, move inside the`LCD-show` folder and Install it (everything with just one command):

   ```
   tar xzvf /boot/LCD-show-YYMMDD.tar.gz; cd LCD-show/; ./LCD35-show
   ```

Touch function will work after restart.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, this is the recommended way by Kuman too.

Comment: @jet It requires to have Xserver..? Can I just use framebuffer..?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and here is how I solved it, this is the error message:

```
[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2).
```

What I found was that the root file setting in the `cmdline.txt` entry that the driver tries to install was incompatible with the setting in the original `/boot/cmdline.txt`.

e.g. The original `cmdline.txt` has `root=/dev/mmcblk0p7` where the driver tries to overwrite it has `root=/dev/mmcblk0p2`.

After changing `mmcblk0p2` to `mmcblk0p7`, the system boots up and the LCD screen works.

Comment: I used the waveshare drivers and this was the exact fix to the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

You likely have noobs installed.  The premade package by Pi.org. You need Raspbian Jessie-PIXEL.  Unfortunately some root files are set up differently in the Noobs installation.  To avoid future inconveniences I suggest using Raspbian jessie pixel over noobs.  I did this, and it stopped so many errors from occurring.  Noobs also prevents the installation of other software and firmware.  I always thought Noobs and Raspbian were the same...  Guess not.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i had the same problem,
i find meanwhile a image that works
http://projektsmartmirror.jimdo.com/lcd-display-am-raspberry/

But as soon you upgrade Raspian to the actual version then agein the same error as you get.

I hope this helps to use the diaplay

Comment: Thanks, ill try it right now, and if you're german (bcus of the website), danke :D

Comment: The image works as far as i can use the LCD as a Screen, but thats what i had already before. How did you get the touch to work? Mine just isn't working.

Comment: Your link doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I had a world of problems with my Kuman provided touchscreen and OS.  I emailed them many times and in the end they sent me a new screen (I didn't even get a white screen on powering on) and their .img on a disc.  After that I downloaded the latest waveshare driver following the instructions [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54906/android-operating-system-with-touchscreen/54913#54913) and all worked - I still have an issue with text not wrapping on the boot screen but I can live with that.  Maybe try a fresh Raspbian img and get the latest driver.

Answer (score 0):

I've also purchased a kuman 3.5 LCD and ran into similar issues. The screen comes with a micro sd card with Raspian already installed with the drivers installed. That was fantastic until 5 minutes later I did

```
sudo apt-get update
```

followed by

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

after the system reboot I would give me the same kernel panic. I contacted the seller and they told me to reinstall the os from the link provided. I did and got it to work but no touch functions. In terminal enter

```
sudo apt-mark hold raspberrypi-kernel
```

and that should stop the error when upgrading. You also have to install the correct driver. It's best to do this using ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar as one of the answers above - including my first ever Kernel panic !

The error message was:

```
[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2).
```

After looking up in the boot partition of my SD card, I saw indeed the cmdline.txt had been modified from the original line:

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p7
```

The LCD driver overwrote it has

```
root=/dev/mmcblk0p2
```

I changed the `cmdline.txt` in `/boot/LCD-show/` that used "mmcblk0p2" instead of "mmcblk0p7" to avoid the problem.

I'm still looking for a solution to use both the HDMI and the LCD at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue with a kuman 3.5 inch LCD touchscreen:

- boot error
- LCD whitescreen
  i have the last version of NOOBS (03/12/2017) and the kuman software.

> I had the same problem with the error [ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2).
>
> What I found was that the root file setting in the "cmdline.txt" entry that the driver tries to install was incompatible with the setting in the original "/boot/cmdline.txt". E.g. The original cmdline.txt has "root=/dev/mmcblk0p7" where the driver tries to overwrite it has "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2". After changing "mmcblk0p2" to "mmcblk0p7", the system boots up and the LCD screen works.

This actually works but in the kuman software, cmdline.txt file is in /usr repository, do the modification and the basic installation will work.

Enjoy