# Has anyone tried connecting a adafruit hat board and an LCD Screen?

Tags: gpio, hardware, pitft, hat

We use the Raspberry Pi 3 boards for an elementary school robotics program.  We saw these cool Kuman 3.5" touch screens that said they were HDMI (which I assumed meant they connected directly into the HDMI port).  It appears as though they have to connect to the GPIO pins directly on the PI board.

The problem is we use the Adafruit Servo/PWM Pi Hat boards to control our servos for the wheels and such which utilizes all of the pins.

If we don't use the pins would that just turn it into a Monitor instead of a touch screen?  (Loses its coolness, but at least it can still function as a portable monitor).

The picture attached shows how the monitor needs to be attached on the left side and the right side is with the ADAFRUIT board we need to have attached as well.

Can these two setups somehow be combined?  Any help is appreciated!  Thank you!

[image: Two different setups.. Can they be combined somehow?]

Comment: See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55522/how-can-i-install-the-kuman-3-5-inch-display which indicates access to the GPIO pins are needed for touch screen. See also https://www.hackster.io/manuelfelipe_ramos/how-to-install-kuman-tft-3-5-for-raspberry-pi-and-retropie-c49800 which also indicates access to the GPIO pins are needed. I don't see any indication of HDMI connectors. What is the specific model number of the screen?

Comment: You can just dump the Servo HAT and use my pigpio library (or servoblaster etc.).

Comment: When purchased I went on the AMAZON description which said HDMI output... now that we have it I want to try and utilize it as a touch screen if possible, but realize without the GPIO pins that may not be achievable.  I will research the pigpio as I have no understanding of what that is.  We were given these without much assistance of using them other than ... here you go!  The instructions state it is MPI3508 model.