# Kuman 3.5 in. Touchscreen display not working

Tags: display

I just bought the Kuman 3.5 inch touchscreen display for the Raspberry pi, and I installed all of the drivers correctly using this link: [How can I install the KUMAN 3.5 inch-display?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55522/how-can-i-install-the-kuman-3-5-inch-display)


After I finished installing them, the system rebooted, but i got an error saying:

```
---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)
```

and I don't know how to fix it.
People were saying

> What I found was that the root file setting in the "cmdline.txt" entry that the >driver tries to install was incompatible with the setting in the original "/boot/cmdline.txt". E.g. The original cmdline.txt has "root=/dev/mmcblk0p7" where the driver tries to overwrite it has "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2". After changing "mmcblk0p2" to "mmcblk0p7", the system boots up and the LCD screen works

and

> Download driver: http://www.waveshare.com/w/upload/3/3d/LCD-show-160811.tar.gz
>
> Add to `/boot/config.txt`
>
> ```
> max_usb_current=1
> hdmi_group=2
> hdmi_mode=87
> hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
> ```
>
> Install: `tar xzvf /boot/LCD-show-YYMMDD.tar.gz; cd LCD-show/; ./LCD35-show`
>
> Touch function will work after restart...

They were all mentioning various .txt files, so I tried looking in my pi's microSD card, but nothing was there.
I do not want to flash a ROM to it, because my computer isn't working well and I don't have that much time. Is there any quick fix to this problem?
Thanks!

Comment: `nothing was there` ... do you mean that the SD card is blank?

Comment: No, I have the raspbian installation files, and a bunch of backup files, but I can't locate the files from github. My raspi did say that the cloning completed successfully. Is it something to do with partitions that my computer can't read?