# 3.5 Kuman touchscreen rotation

Tags: touchscreen

How can I rotate my touchscreen display 180 so that I can stand it up with the power coming out of the top, rather than the bottom as it does now?
Thanks
(I'm a total novice with Linux so please be gentle)

Comment: For those who are trying to figure out how to correct/calibrate the touch on the 5 inch screen this page has the instructions for that. https://mega.nz/#F!HUFQFDwL!fhM7RPrhbMJLsZ7ISLEr0A!2JNQAaII

Comment: **Beware the above URL has been flagged as potentially involved in phishing:** https://www.virustotal.com/#/url/71216ea7e98991af2c7f6226d581d2ba513e14cc585f8e8d0f6cf04bf112f755/detection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have one of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01HZPOTFY) (different size is fine too), they are compatible with/same as the waveshare products available [here](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)).

[image: TFT]

## Using LCD-show drivers and scripts

I have posted the setup details [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54913/33810). As part of the driver bundle there are number of scripts and the instructions to configure the orientations  are also available on that site.

Here's an extract

> Toggle between LCD and HDMI display
>   Once this LCD is enabled, meanwhile the default settings for HDMI are changed. If you want to use another HDMI monitor, please run the following command:
>
> cd LCD-show/
>       ./LCD-hdmi
>
> This toggles the mode to LCD display:
>
> ```
> ./LCD35-show
> ```
>
> Screen orientation settings
>
> After touch driver installed, the screen orientation can be set by these 
>   commands:
>
> 0 degree rotation
>
> ```
> cd LCD-show/
> ./LCD35-show 0
> ```
>
> 90 degree rotation
>
> ```
> cd LCD-show/
> ./LCD35-show 90
> ```
>
> 180 degree rotation
>
> ```
> cd LCD-show/
> ./LCD35-show 180
> ```
>
> 270 degree rotation
>
> ```
> cd LCD-show/
> ./LCD35-show 270
> ```

## Alternative solution

If the LCD-show script doesn't work for your configuration you can also try and edit the boot configuration manually. That is what these scripts do anyway:

```
sudo nano /boot/config.txt
```

Look for a line `dtoverlay=waveshare35a` or any other display identifier after `dtoverlay=`. To that line you can append `,rotate=` like so:

```
dtoverlay=waveshare35a,rotate=90
```

Next exit nano and save changes with `ctrl+x` followed by `Y` and `ENTER`. This requires a reboot to take effect:

```
sudo reboot
```

Note that if you're using a touchscreen you'll also have to swap the touch X and Y axis. For more information check [this display configuration overview](http://www.spotpear.com/learn/EN/raspberry-pi/Raspberry-Pi-LCD/Raspberry-Pi-_Rotate-the-screen-display.html).

Comment: Yep it's that screen, I tried:  cd LCD-show/
./LCD35-show 180, the screen rebooted as nothing has changed

Comment: Success!!  I went back and followed the whole process in your link above, and then did the cd ./LCD-show   and ./LDC35-show 180 command and it worked!  Thank you so much!!

Comment: Done!  Sorry I'm very new to this :)  Again, thank you!

Comment: No apologies required, everyone has to start somewhere :)

Comment: This answer got me going on the right track.  The rotation values are spelled out here: https://github.com/goodtft/LCD-show/issues/34

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `display_rotate=2` to `/boot/config.txt`. Reboot required.

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md

---

You may also want to try adding `lcd_rotate=2` instead of `display_rotate=2`.

Source: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/display/troubleshooting.md

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these options worked :(

Comment: This answer only works for the "official" display and not for the mentioned display.

Answer (score 0):

The Switch between HDMI and the touch Display is done by rewriting all of the config files and Drivers.
Try editing the corresponding files behind the LCD35show first.